# Sidereal time calculation in C

Tags: c, algorithm, computational-geometry

I have some code which I taken from Javascript. Original purpose of the program was to calculate Solar Radiation. It calculates Solar Position, Earth Distance from Sun, Hour Angle, Zenith, Azimuth  etc. I tried to analize one part of the program which I have rewritten to C. This is the part where sidereal time is calculated.

**Just for context purposes:**

```
  // Sidereal time (Theta0)
  double GMST = 280.46061837+360.98564736629*( i->JulianDate-2451545.);
  // Sidereal_time = GMST + 0.000387933*T2 - T3/38710000
  double Sidereal_time = GMST+0.000387933*T*T
       -T*T*T/38710000.;
```

Note: i->JulianDate  is Julian Date, which is calculated from user input date.

I have also found some interesting source which describes how to calculate sitereal time [here](http://www2.arnes.si/~gljsentvid10/sidereal.htm).

**The question**

Now the part of the code, where I am wondering about it:

```
// Replacement code for Sidereal=fmod(Sidereal,360.)
double S_save=Sidereal_time/360.;

if (S_save < 0.) Sidereal_time=Sidereal_time-ceil(S_save)*360.;
else Sidereal_time=Sidereal_time-floor(S_save)*360.;

if (Sidereal_time < 0.) Sidereal_time+=360.;
```

Can you explain to me why this block of condition is there? I see the note: *Sidereal=fmod(Sidereal,360.)* But I don't see why the author replaced the short code with the long block of conditional statements. Any ideas welcome.

Comment: It's trying to restrict the values between 0.0 and 360.0 *without* using the library function [`fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod). Maybe the author thinks to gain better performance and knows that `Sideral_time` isn't too far away from the limits.

Comment: fmod - computes the floating-point remainder of the division operation... why not use just `SideReal%360` ? Could it be suitable to replace the code with this short statement?

Comment: @user1141649 SideReal is of type double, so modulus won't work well.

Comment: I have meassured how long time it takes to use the fmod and different ways and in all cases I got 0.000003s. In Debug mode without optimalization. So I don't see the performance difference. But I have read here that fmod is quite slow: https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/105096-fmod.html (I tested the method presented there too same time 0.3E05).

Answer (score 2):

Well, the "replacement" code does something different for negative numbers. This is the proof:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double fmod360_alternative(double Sidereal_time) {
    double S_save=Sidereal_time/360.;

    if (S_save < 0.) Sidereal_time=Sidereal_time-ceil(S_save)*360.;
    else Sidereal_time=Sidereal_time-floor(S_save)*360.;

    if (Sidereal_time < 0.) Sidereal_time+=360.;

    return Sidereal_time;
}

int main() {
    double Sidereal_time = -100;
    cout << fmod(Sidereal_time,360.0) << endl;   // result: -100
    cout << fmod360_alternative(Sidereal_time) << endl; // result: 260
    return 0;
}
```

As Bob__ said in the comment section, the "replacement" code keeps the end result in the interval `[0.0,360.0)`. `fmod` does not.

However, I agree the "replacement" code is more complicated than necessary. But you should keep in mind that not everybody writing code is a programmer and in the space industry (or related) there are a lot of physicists required to write code at some point and they sometimes go for the correctness of the results, rather than performance (which is ok).